# Экспорт игры на айпад 2 не проходит

Tags: export

Всем привет,

заранее извиняюсь за некомпетентность, кто нибудь знает почему у меня не проходит экспорт игры на айпад2 судя по этому скрину? На айфон идет без проблем, а при экспорте на айпад обрывается выводя сообщение об обрыве связи с девайсом. Заранее спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]